# Hair simulation not rendering in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair

I was trying to add hair dynamics to a mesh. While hair particles without any dynamics render fine, as soon as I turn on the simulation the hair disappears from the render. I've checked and it's not a clipping issue, and the simulated hair is perfectly visible in render view, but not in the final render. I really have no ideas of what's happening. I'm running Blender v2.83.0 .